# ExtJs4: Quirks mode or Strict mode in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, extjs, extjs4, doctype

i need to know what is the really difference with Quirks mode and Strict mode or what is my problem with Doctype.

I'm developing a complex layout app with extjs4.2.1: when i start to develop that i declare the DOCTYPE (`<!doctype html>`) in all my page. But in my first experience of test i realize there is a lot of problem with the css rendering in IE (i test only IE9 and IE10), like don't see all css or the autowith of them have some problem, some icon never visualize etc. I try (only for test) to change the class of the html document from strict to quirks mode deleting the doctype declaration in the page and then all (for now) is work fine.

My question is why? There is some thing that i have to know?

Comment: Use the F12 dev tools to see what mode the browser is in. You should try to always keep the page in standards mode. Quirks mode has major issues, but there's also compatibility mode to watch out for, which you should also avoid.

Comment: I'm already using F12 dev tools (in IE and chrome) and FireBug..when i put the docktype the mode is strict mode, and when i remove the docktype the mode (present in the html class property) is quirks mode. I need to know if there is any known problems  in the absence of the doctype..

Comment: absence of doctype == quirks mode. And yes, there are lots of problems with quirks mode. Quirks mode means "*disable most of the browser features, including most CSS, and change some of the basic layout for what is left*". You should avoid quirks mode at all costs.

Comment: mmmm...Can you explain me better what is the problems with quirks mode: for now i test my application with many type of browser using and don't using doctype and otherwise that you explain only with doctype i have css problem with IE9/IE10..

Comment: Quirks mode is designed to copy old browsers (from about 1998). There are lots of things that quirks mode might do differently to normal, but the most important point is that different browsers implement quirks mode differently (and some may not even have quirks mode), so you can't expect quirks mode to work the same in any two browsers. Standards mode *should* work exactly the same in all browsers.

Comment: OK, in Italy we say that i found the exception that proves the rule..

Comment: I would be very surprised if you have; I would imagine there's something else going on here that you've misssed, but without seeing your site I really can't give you any further clues about what's actually happening.